# How to send context to BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver

I want to use my BroadcastReceiver as sender of data into my activity. For this reason I'm using `LocalBroadcastManager`. This manager is used to register and unregister my receiver. Problem is that `Context` in `onReceive` method is different than `Context` in `onStart` and `onStop` method.

I need to pass activity context into my `BroadcastReceiver` or instance of `LocalBroadcastManager` initialized inside `Activity`. Because my receiver is not receiving any data.

Maybe it is not fault of this manager context but I don't know why it doesnt work since I implemented this manager.

```
class GPSReceiver: BroadcastReceiver(){

    companion object{
        const val GPS_PAYLOAD = "gps_payload"
    }

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        try {
            val locationManager = context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager
            val int = Intent(GPS_PAYLOAD)
            if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                int.putExtra(GPS_PAYLOAD, true)
            } else {
                int.putExtra(GPS_PAYLOAD, false)
            }
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(int)
        } catch (ex: Exception) {

        }
    }
}
```

Registering receiver inside Activity:

```
private val gpsStatusReceiver = object: BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
            App.log("isGpsEnabled: onReceive")
            val gpsStatus = intent?.extras?.getBoolean(GPS_PAYLOAD)
            if (gpsStatus != null) {
                if (gpsStatus){
                    App.log("isGpsEnabled: true")
                    hideGpsSnackbar()
                } else {
                    App.log("isGpsEnabled: false")
                    showGpsSnackbar()
                }
            } else {
                App.log("isGpsEnabled: null")
            }
        }
    }

override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).apply {
            val filter = IntentFilter()
            filter.apply {
                addAction("android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED")
                addAction(GPS_PAYLOAD)
            }
            registerReceiver(gpsStatusReceiver, filter)
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to call getApplicationContext() on the context of the Receiver.

Comment: And how do I get applicationContext inside receiver. I cant call getApplicationContext() there

Comment: I cant pass context into my constructor, because for Android 6.0 receiver is created from Android Manifest and there is no constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen your code.  So there is not issue with context, but in the approach.
Your are registering your reciever with the same strings in which you are getting you data inside the Reciever. 
So Send Your broadcast from Fragment/Activity

**Send BroadCast Like**

```
private fun sendSuccessfulCheckoutEvent() {
        val intent = Intent("successful_checkout_event")
        intent.putExtra("cartID", cartId)
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent)
    }
```

And Listen it in Activity/Fragment like this

**1) Create broadcast Reciever**

```
private val checkoutDoneReciever : BroadcastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver(){
        override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
             val cartNumbers = intent.getIntExtra("cartID", 0)
              Log.d("receiver", "Got message: $cartNumbers.toString()")
        }
    }
```

**2) Register it in onCreate()/onStart()**

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(cartUpdatedReceiver,IntentFilter("successful_checkout_event"))
```

**3) Unregister it in onDestroy()**

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(cartUpdatedReceiver)
```